# Using recurrence relations to prove a function has exponential runtime?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, recursion, big-o

Here is a simple C program:

```
int f(int n) {
  if(n==0 || n==1) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return 2 * f(n - 1) + 3 * f(n - 2);
  }
}
```

This program has exponential time complexity.  You can see this in this diagram of the function calls for `f(5)`:

[image: n = 5]

I want to show that the function has exponential complexity using a recurrence equation only, not by drawing a diagram and counting the number of function calls.

The recurrence relation I came up with is

> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c

Expanding gives

> T(n) = 2T(n - 2) + T(n - 3) + 2c

However, I don't know how to solve this further.  How can I solve this recurrence relation?

Comment: Please re-read the lecture notes.

Comment: To enable you to go to the bar - read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters, your recurrence needs some kind of base case, since otherwise it's undefined when you hit 0.  For simplicity, let's say that

> T(0) = a
>
> T(1) = a + b
>
> T(n + 2) = T(n) + T(n + 1) + c

Let's start expanding out the first few terms of this recurrence:

- T(0) = a
- T(1) = a + b
- T(2) = 2a + b + c
- T(3) = 3a + 2b + 2c
- T(4) = 5a + 3b + 4c
- T(5) = 8a + 5b + 7c
- T(6) = 13a + 8b + 12c
- T(7) = 21a + 13b + 20c

There's a very interesting pattern taking shape here.  Let's look individually at the coefficients of the a, b, and c terms.  The coefficients of the a terms follow the pattern

> 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...

This is the Fibonacci series, offset by one step.  The coefficients of the b terms are

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...

Which is *exactly* the Fibonacci series.  Finally, let's look at the c terms:

> 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, ...

Hmmm, that doesn't look familiar.  However, if we put it side-by-side with the a terms, we see this:

> a: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...
>
> b: 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, ...

Notice that the b terms are all the a terms with one subtracted out!  In other words, it's the Fibonacci series shifted by one step, but with 1 subtracted from each term.

Based on these observations, we can conjecture that the following is true:

> T(n) = aF<sub>n+1</sub> + bF<sub>n</sub> + c(F<sub>n+1</sub> - 1)

We can now try to prove this by induction.  As our base cases:

> T(0) = a = 1a + 0b + 0c = 1a + 0b + (1 - 1)c = aF<sub>1</sub> + bF<sub>0</sub> + c(F<sub>1</sub> - 1)
>
> T(1) = a + b = 1a + 1b + 0c = 1a + 1b + (1 - 1)c = aF<sub>2</sub> + bF<sub>1</sub> + c(F<sub>2</sub> - 1)

For our inductive step, let's assume that for some natural number n, that

> T(n) = aF<sub>n+1</sub> + bF<sub>n</sub> + c(F<sub>n+1</sub> - 1)

and that

> T(n + 1) = aF<sub>n+2</sub> + bF<sub>n + 1</sub> + c(F<sub>n+2</sub> - 1)

Then we have that

> T(n + 2) = T(n) + T(n + 1) + c
>
> = aF<sub>n+1</sub> + bF<sub>n</sub> + c(F<sub>n+1</sub> - 1) + aF<sub>n+2</sub> + bF<sub>n + 1</sub> + c(F<sub>n+2</sub> - 1) + c
>
> = a(F<sub>n+1</sub> + F<sub>n+2</sub>) + b(F<sub>n</sub> + F<sub>n+1</sub>) + c(F<sub>n+1</sub> + F<sub>n+2</sub> - 2 + 1)
>
> = aF<sub>n+3</sub> + bF<sub>n+2</sub> + c(F<sub>n+3</sub> - 1)

This completes the induction, so our formula must be correct!

So how does this relate to efficiency?  Well, [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) tells us that F<sub>n</sub> = Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>), where φ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) (about 1.61).  This means that

> T(n) = aF<sub>n+1</sub> + bF<sub>n</sub> + c(F<sub>n+1</sub> - 1) = aΘ(φ<sup>n</sup>) + bΘ(φ<sup>n</sup>) + cΘ(φ<sup>n</sup>) = Θ((a + b + c)φ<sup>n</sup>)

So as long as a + b + c ≠ 0, the runtime is Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>), which is exponential.

Hope this helps!

Comment: wonderful explanation, how can you write this good answer with in 9 mins ..you seems from theory of computation background...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan- I teach a theory of computation course and already happened to know the basic idea behind this particular recurrence.  It's primarily from experience.

Comment: Nice!! I also love to teaching and teach theory of computation But I am software Engineer, I just saw your home page nice answers I would like to read in my extra time...and I will catch you when I will find some question/doubt

Comment: I'd add to the above that if you want to derive the recurrence instead of guessing (and proving that guess with induction!) then you might want to look into generating functions: http://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2005/fall/27100-1/gf.pdf

It requires more math (read: algebra), but it's more constructive. I think most complexity classes teach you this method in addition to guessing + induction, so you guys should get to it eventually?